# How to get qInfo() as a QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator

I'm trying to access the coordinates of a `MapQuickItem` in QML from C++. The latitude has 9 decimal digits and longitude has 8 decimal digits. But if I try to access them using `latitude()`, I lose the last 5 decimal places. If I try to use `toString(QGeoCoordinate::Degrees)`, I only get 5 decimal digits. But when I print out the `QGeoCoordinate` directly using `qInfo()`, it shows all 9 digits.

Is there a way to grab the `qInfo()` output and store them inside a `QString`, or otherwise get the full decimal places of the latitude and longitude?

C++:

```
QObject *pin = qvariant_cast<QObject *>(mapObject -> property("destination"));
QGeoCoordinate dest = qvariant_cast<QGeoCoordinate>(pin->property("coordinate"));
qInfo() << "dest: " << dest;
qInfo() << dest.toString(QGeoCoordinate::Degrees);
qInfo() << dest.latitude();
qInfo() << dest.longitude();
```

Output:

```
dest:  QGeoCoordinate(33.751513868, -118.1781581, 0)
"33.75151°, -118.17816°, 0m"
33.7515
-118.178
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [qSetRealNumberPrecision](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextstream.html#setRealNumberPrecision) or [QString::number](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#number-6).

```
double d = 123456789.987654321;
qInfo() << qSetRealNumberPrecision(15) << d;
qInfo() << QString::number(d, 'f', 6);
```

Output

```
123456789.987654
"123456789.987654"
```

---

```
QGeoCoordinate coordinate(33.751513868, -118.1781581, 0);

qInfo() << coordinate;
qInfo() << qSetRealNumberPrecision(11) << coordinate.latitude()
                                       << coordinate.longitude();
qInfo() << QString::number(coordinate.latitude(), 'f', 9)
        << QString::number(coordinate.longitude(), 'f', 9);
```

Output

```
QGeoCoordinate(33.751513868, -118.1781581, 0)
33.751513868 -118.1781581
"33.751513868" "-118.178158100"
```